# How do you create a Azure Web app with a python runtime of 3.6 using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

Terraform 0.13 returns an error when you try to use python_version =3.6 when creating a Azure App Service for a kind=Linux.  It looks like this is not a valid option in Terraform but it is an valid option in Azure.  Is there a different option I need to look at?  python_Version 3.4 is not supported by Azure in this configuration.

Example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ref-webapp-group" {                   
  name     = "${var.ref-prefix}-webapp-rg"                               
  location = "eastus2"                                                   
                                                                         
  tags = var.common-tags                                                 
}                                                                        
                                                                         
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {                   
  name                = "SOMEPREFIX-appserviceplan"                         
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.name     
  kind = "Linux"                                                         
  reserved = true                                                        
                                                                         
  sku {                                                                  
    tier = "Standard"                                                    
    size = "S1"                                                          
  }                                                                      
}                                                                        
                                                                         
resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp" {                                
  name                = "SOMEPREFIX-webapp"                                 
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.name     
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id       
                                                                         
  site_config {                                                          
    python_version = 3.6                                                 
  }                                                                      
                                                                         
  app_settings = {                                                       
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"                                            
  }                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so with a little bit of investigation it looks like you can use the linux_fx_version argument to do deploy the different run times.  You can use the command:

```
az webapp list-runtimes --linux
```

to list the runtimes and then you can put it into a terraform script like so:

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ref-webapp-group" {                     
   name     = "${var.ref-prefix}-webapp-rg"                                 
   location = "eastus2"                                                     
                                                                            
   tags = var.common-tags                                                   
 }                                                                          
                                                                            
 resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {                     
   name                = "SOMEPREFIX-appserviceplan"                           
   location            = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.location   
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.name       
   kind = "Linux"                                                           
   reserved = true                                                          
                                                                            
   sku {                                                                    
     tier = "Standard"                                                      
     size = "S1"                                                            
   }                                                                        
 }                                                                          
                                                                            
 resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp" {                                  
   name                = "SOMEPREFIX-webapp"                                   
   location            = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.location   
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ref-webapp-group.name       
   app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id         
                                                                            
   site_config {                                                            
     linux_fx_version = "PYTHON|3.6"                                        
   }                                                                        
                                                                            
   app_settings = {                                                         
     "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"                                              
   }                                                                        
 }
```

This is not documented anywhere I could find in the Terraform docs and I could not find it documented by Microsoft anywhere in there docs.  I did find it sort of on a git hub bug for Microsoft docs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47749

Comment: As an option, you can create the App Service with the desired configuration manually in Azure, create empty terraform resource, and import the created App Service using `terraform import` command.
The next run of the `terraform plan` will show you the exact configuration to create the desired resource, you just need to move it to the resource.